# Find minimum value in a column of dates?

Tags: python, petl

I have a column of dates, I'm trying to figure out what is the earliest date of the table and then insert a row above it with certain values. I'm using `petl` but can't seem to figure out how to use `min` on a column of date values. Is that even doable?

Comment: did you try using min(df['date_column'])

Comment: If the values are dates of any standard supported type, merely use the vector operation `min` on the column.  @user3687197 gave you one such suggestion.  If the dates are *not* in a standard type, convert them to Python's `datetime` or equivalent type.

Comment: Actually not using `pandas`, does df still work with vanilla python?